# How to split dataframe on based on columns row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have one excel file , dataframe have 20 rows . after few rows there is again column names row, i want to divide dataframe based on column names row.

here is example:

```
x
0
1
2
3
4
x
23
34
5
6
```

expected output is:

```
df1
x
0
1
2
3
4
df2
x
23
34
5
6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering your column name is `col` , you can first group the dataframe taking a [`cumsum`](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GCEU_enIN822IN823&sxsrf=ACYBGNRUM451Ec0GRa2eoKJL3lUel9gdvg%3A1568800408395&ei=mP6BXeXfF53Ez7sP26mTuAI&q=df+cumsum&oq=df+cumsum&gs_l=psy-ab.3...1689.2094..2234...0.0..0.182.182.0j1......0....1..gws-wiz.ailbZ6jJV_Y&ved=0ahUKEwjli8P4jNrkAhUd4nMBHdvUBCcQ4dUDCAs&uact=5) on the `col` where the value equals `x` by `df['col'].eq('x').cumsum()` , then for each group create a dataframe by taking the values from the 2nd row of that group and the columns as the first value of that group using `df.iloc[]` and save them in a dictionary:

```
d={f'df{i}':pd.DataFrame(g.iloc[1:].values,columns=g.iloc[0].values) 
                   for i,g in df.groupby(df['col'].eq('x').cumsum())}
```

---

```
print(d['df1'])
 x
0  0
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4

print(d['df2'])
    x
0  23
1  34
2   5
3   6
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `df.index[df['x'] == 'x']` to look for the row index of where the column name appears again. 
Then, split the dataframe into 2 based on the index found

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['x'], data=[[0], [1], [2], [3], [4], ['x'], [23], [34], [5], [6]])

df1 = df.iloc[:df.index[df['x'] == 'x'].tolist()[0]]
df2 = df.iloc[df.index[df['x'] == 'x'].tolist()[0]+1:]
```

Answer (score 1):

You did't mention this is sample of your dataset.Then you can try this

```
import pandas as pd 

df1 = []
df2 = []

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'df1': ['x', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'df2': ['x', 23, 34, 5, 6]})

display(df1, df2)
```